# Summing 2D vector

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

I have a 2D vector and I need to calculate the sum of all the elements inside the block (Yes - I have asked this problem before, but, I need further help)..

Basically, in MATLAB I am getting the result of: 0.4259 whereas in C++ I get the result of: 1270.91.

First what I do is I split the matrix (1D) into blocks (600x200) following this algorithm (IN MATLAB):

```
function f = block(v, N, M)
%   N = 30 msec (600 samples)
%   M = 10 msec (200 samples)

n = length(v);
maxblockstart = n - N + 1;
lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1 , M);

% Remove the semicolon to see the number of blocks
% numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1
  numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

f = zeros(numblocks,N);

for i = 1:numblocks
 for j = 1:N
   f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
end
end
```

This in C++:

```
vector< vector<double> > Audio::something(vector<double>& theData, int N, int M)
{
int n = theData.size();
int maxblockstart = n - N;
int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart % M);

int numblocks = (lastblockstart)/M + 1;
vector< vector<double> > subBlock;
vector<double> temp;
this->width = N;
this->height = numblocks;

subBlock.resize(600*187);
for(int i=0; (i < 600); i++)
{
    subBlock.push_back(vector<double>());
    for(int j=0; (j < 187); j++)
    {   
        subBlock[i].push_back(theData[i*N+j]);
    } 
}    
return subBlock;
```

}

This looks perfectly fine to me, I can't see a problem with it.

Now for the summation, in MATLAB:

```
len = length(blocks);
n = sum(size(blocks)) - len;
min = n+1;
max = 0;

for i = 1:n
  currsum = abs(blocks(i,1:len));
end
f = currsum;
```

In C++:

```
vector<double>     Audio::filter(vector<iniMatrix>&blocks, double sumThres, double ZeroThres)
{
int n = this->height;

int min = n+1;
int max = 0;
int length = blocks.size();
double currsum = 0;

for(int i=0; (i < 600); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; (j < 187); j++)
    {
        currsum += abs(blocks[j][i]);
        //currsum = currsum / 600;
        //cout << abs(blocks[0][j]) << endl;
        //cout << currsum << endl;
    }
}
cout << currsum;
```

}

I can't seem to find where I am going wrong.. I'm following the algorithm to the exact point and don't understand why the numbers are so high. I did some output in MATLAB and found this:

```
    Columns 1 through 10

    0.0013    0.0011    0.0010    0.0009    0.0012    0.0012    0.0012    0.0014    0.0016    
    0.0016

  Columns 11 through 20

    0.0017    0.0019    0.0018    0.0014    0.0011    0.0011    0.0012    0.0010    0.0010    
    0.0011

  Columns 21 through 30

    0.0011    0.0010    0.0009    0.0006    0.0005    0.0002    0.0003    0.0007    0.0008    
    0.0009
```

.. This goes on until 600 (Counting/Showing 9 Values).

Does this mean that MATLAB is only summing up these values (9 values per column) 600 times?

I'm really confused and hopefully someone can help me :)!

Comment: I don't get it, you have a 2D vector (matrix) and you want to sum its elements? That is simply sum(sum(v)). You want to sum a block? That is sum(sum(v(start_row:end_row,start_col:end_col))). You say 2D vector and 1D matrix... I think you are confusing some terms.

Comment: The question is very confusing. What is the actual problem to solve, what are the inputs, what are the expected outputs, what are you getting, why do you think that is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MATLAB code is not actually performing a sum.  Your first clue should be that your output is a vector rather than a scalar.  You are calling `abs()` on each block of 600 values (which results in another 600-element vector), and overwriting currsum with that vector each time.

I have no idea why your code includes sum(size(blocks)), but for the sum, try just

```
f = sum(sum(abs(blocks)));
```

Other notes: In MATLAB it is more typical to store each window as a column rather than as a row.  If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, use the command `buffer` to produce your overlapping windows from a single command.  Then, commands like `sum` will operate by default down the columns, so you can call it once and get the sum of each of your windows.

Comment: If you don't mind (pointing it out), what is the MATLAB code performing?

Comment: Since you're new to MATLAB, the best way to figure out how things work is to experiment.  The code is small enough that you can run pieces of it at the command line and see what happens.  For example, if you don't know what the syntax `blocks(i,1:len)` does, then try it on a 10x10 matrix and see.  If you don't know what `abs` is, then run `help abs` or `doc abs` and read, then try abs([1 2 3 -1 -2 -3]) and see what happens.

Comment: Than you for your reply. Ok, I know what most of them do, I just do not understand why this code is returning values from 1-10, 11-20 etc.. Is the code only selecting 10 values OR is the code only showing 10 values as an example? Thanks :)

Comment: It is printing one large result of size 1x600.  However, you can't fit 600 values (columns of the matrix) horizontally on the screen, so MATLAB is showing you 10 at a time.  In your head, take the printouts from 11-20 and put them to the right of the values for 1-10.  Also, try displaying these two values in MATLAB, and note the difference: `x=(1:20)` vs. `x=(1:20)'`